# What does the notation $\mathcal{N}(z; \mu, \sigma)$ stand for in statistics?

Tags: terminology, variational-autoencoder, notation, random-variable, bayesian-statistics

I know that the notation $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ stands for a normal distribution.
But I'm reading the book "An Introduction to Variational Autoencoders" and in it, there is this notation:
$$\mathcal{N}(z; 0, I)$$
What does it mean?

picture of the book:
[image: picture of the book An Introduction to Variational Autoencoders]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118284/discussion-on-question-by-peyman-what-does-the-notation-mathcalnz-mu-si).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that $z$ has a (multivariate) normal distribution with 0 mean and identity covariance matrix. This essentially means each individual element of the vector $z$ has a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118283/discussion-on-answer-by-david-ireland-what-does-the-notation-mathcalnz-mu).